# How to convert series to dataframe if the series is separated by comma using python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Converting series to dataframe:

I tried this:

```
df = pd.Series(data)
df1=pd.DataFrame(df,sep=",")
print(df1)
```

This is the series format:

```
0     (The Associated Press, Shock in Japan as Nissa...
1     (The Associated Press, Shock in Japan as Nissa...
2     (The Associated Press, Venezuelan ambassador t...
3     (None, WATCH: World News 11/19/18: Deadly Shoo...
4     (The Associated Press, AP Photos: Northeastern...
5     (The Associated Press, Esi Edugyan wins prize ...
6     (The Associated Press, China's Xi visits Manil...
```

Comment: What is `print (data[:3])` ?

Comment: Does my answer fit to your need ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
pd.DataFrame(df.tolist())
```

since the series is in a list format.This line works.

Output:

```
                                         0                          1
0                     The Associated Press  Shock in Japan as Nissan's Ghosn held in..

1                     The Associated Press  Shock in Japan as Nissan's Ghosn held.. 

2                     The Associated Press   Venezuelan ambassador to Cuba Ali Rodriguez..

3                                     None  WATCH: World News 11/19/18: Deadly Shooting...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data)
df1 = df1.replace({'(': '', ')': ''})
df1 = df1[0].str.split(',',expand=True)

df1 = df1.rename(columns={0: 'col1', 1: 'col2'})

print(df1)
```

Comment: Please provide some context.

Comment: i am fetching the data from database and displaying it in series and want to convert it to dataframe